# Occasional slow performance copying data across projects in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have encountered very slow movement when copying data across one project to another project located in the same data location in bigquery, however it took up to 2 minutes for the data being moved which is just about 100,000 records, as compared to other operations we have done on bigquery copying data with hundreds of millions which took only a  matter of a few seconds, hence I would like to find out why this unusual slow movement for such a small data set occurred. Did anyone come across similar issue and have any idea what could be the cause behind it please?

Thanks.

Best regards,

Comment: I suggest to check ur project slot allocation at the time of the copy if you max out it might provide an explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of the slow copy problem could come from method of creation your source table, e.g. it could have been created by several imports jobs that can caused such a fragmentation.

So the difference in time is not because the amount of data stored in your table, but the way the data is fragmented inside.

Although the running time is very reasonable, if you want to speed it up more, you can try COALESCE/MERGE your table. One way of doing this is to export the table to Google Cloud Storage and re-import it back (not append). This should reduce the fragmentation and help in case you want to optimize your operations and gain a few seconds.

Running time of few minutes for table copy method is considered internally as absolutely normal for a table copy job and this does not classify as a BigQuery deficiency.

Refer to [official](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-tables#copy-table) documentation. And if you want to know more about fragmentation in BigQuery, I recommend you O'REILLY "Google BigQuery: The Definitive Guide: Data Warehousing, Analytics, and Machine Learning at Scale" book.

I hope you find the above pieces of information useful.